# firebase login authentication gives me that email must be a valid string

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

It always gives me "first argument (email) must be a valid string" and it doesn't login
i don't know if the problem is in the js code but im pretty sure it's not in the html .
and another question .. do i need the " onAuthStateChanged " function?

```
<script>
var rightAccount = 0;
var email = $("#inputEmail").val();
var password = $("#inputPassword").val();
SignIn();

function SignIn(email,password) {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((user) => {
             authStateListener();
             rightAccount = 1;
             //Signed in
             // ...
     })
     .catch((error) => {
             var errorCode = error.code;
             var errorMessage = error.message;
             console.log(errorMessage);
             alert(errorMessage);
     });
};
                                    
function authStateListener() {
      // [START auth_state_listener]
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                var uid = user.uid;
                currentUser = user;
                console.log(currentUser.email + " has logged in")
            } else {
                // ...
            }
       });
       // [END auth_state_listener]
};
                                                            
if (rightAccount == 1) {
  setTimeout(function Redirect() {
      window.location.replace("Website/homePage.php");
  }, 2000)
}
</script>
```

Comment: What do you see in the console if you add a `console.log` as follows: `function SignIn(email,password) {
console.log(email); firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)...`?

Comment: it gives me "undefined"... does it mean that it dosent read the input value?

Comment: Yes, `var email = $("#inputEmail").val();`does not give the correct value. You may share your HTML code. Also, do you wait until the document is "ready" with `$( document ).ready()`?? See https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: `<input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm text-right" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail">
<input type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm text-right" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword">
<input type="submit" value="تسجيل دخول" class="btn btn-danger w-50" id="sign-in-button" name="signIn">`

Comment: it's a bit messy but those are the inputs i have...and the clicking event on submit button is in php... and actually i don't use the ready function...looks very important anyway .. gonna read the link and add it .

Comment: Yes, the ready function is key. **Especially given the fact you call the SignIn function immediately in your script**. If it solves your problem, tell me and I will write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass email and password values to function. Otherwise it will be give error.

```
...
var email = $("#inputEmail").val();
var password = $("#inputPassword").val();
SignIn(email, password); // <-- Here pass them
...
```